# Invalid csrf token Странное поведение csurf

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules, csrf

Уже **** горит жестко от этой ошибки. Уже несколько дней работаю с этой csurf, всё отлично, всё окей, но начиная с какого-то момента перестал работать на странице продукта (AdminRoutes)
На сайте есть аутентификация, есть формы по типу добавки товара в корзину через форму с csrf токеном и еще несколько таких форм с csrf, везде работает корректно, но именно при добавлении и изменении продукта выдает ошибку Invalid csrf token.
Голова уже не может думать, просто загадка года для меня...
Заранее очень благодарю за помощь.

app.js

```
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session')
const MongoDBSession = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session)
const csrf = require('csurf')
const flash = require('connect-flash')

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express();

const MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb+srv://login:password@mongooset.ekaxg.mongodb.net/shop?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
const sessionStore = new MongoDBSession({
    uri: MONGODB_URI,
    collection: 'session'
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/AdminRoutes');
const shopRoutes = require('./routes/ShopRoutes');
const cartRoutes = require('./routes/CartRoutes');
const orderRoutes = require('./routes/OrderRoutes');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/AuthRoutes');
const User = require('./models/UserModel');
const errorController = require('./controllers/ErrorController')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'some secret key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore,
}));

const csrfProtection = csrf()
app.use(flash())
app.use(csrfProtection)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isAuthenticated
    res.locals.csrf = req.csrfToken()
    next()
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.session.isAuthenticated) {
        return next()
    }
    User.find({ email: req.session.email }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        if (user.length > 0) {
            req.user = user[0]
        } else {
            req.user = []
        }
        return next()
    })
})

app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use(shopRoutes);
app.use(cartRoutes);
app.use(orderRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);

app.use(errorController.get404);

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).render('500', {
        pageTitle: 'Something went wrong',
        page: '500',
    })
})

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected to Mongoose')
        app.listen(8000)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

AdminRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const adminController = require('../controllers/AdminController')
const isAuth = require('../middleware/is-auth')

// GET
router.get('/products', isAuth, adminController.getProducts);
router.get('/add-product', isAuth, adminController.getAddProduct);
router.get('/edit-product/:id', isAuth, adminController.getEditProduct);

// POST
router.post('/add-product', isAuth, adminController.postAddProduct);
router.post('/edit-product/:id', isAuth, adminController.postEditProduct);
router.post('/delete-product', isAuth, adminController.deleteProduct);

module.exports = router
```

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrf %>">
```

csrf токен во всех шаблонах присутствует, проверил уже. Везде одинакого и везде работает, ну кроме этого роута.

Answer (score 0):

Наконец нашел причину. При использовани форм с enctype="multipart/form-data" вместо дефольтного enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" Обязательно поверх app.use(csrf) парсите данные библиотекой, которая парсит формы с multipart/form-data. Иначе поля  будут пустыми в момент проверки csrf токена и соответственно проверку не пройдет, потому что будет сравнивать реальный токен с пустым полем.

```
<form action="/any-action" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

```
app.use(anyMultipartFormDataParser)
const csrfProtection = csrf()
app.use(csrfProtection)
```